# How do I import opencv without using pip?

Tags: python, opencv, github

I'm writing an application in Python 2.5 and I want to be able to import opencv (https://github.com/opencv/opencv) or cv2 without using pip. I want to use opencv or cv2 so that I can programmatically turn a sequence of images to a video. Would this be as simple as copying and pasting all the files from opencv's GitHub onto my GitHub? That way, I could open a source code file from my GitHub and do "import opencv" or "import cv2".

If not, how would I do this?

Comment: Copying c++ source code between repositories will get you no closer to having a usable binary library for Python. You will need to build OpenCV first. There are many questions on SO discussing how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it wouldn't.

Even worse, opencv depends on binary blobs that are compiled, and as such cannot even be installed completely using pip, you would have to either

- Find a binary distribution for your os
- compile it yourself

You will find more information on the openCV documentation, for example [how to install it on Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#install-opencv-python-in-windows). Installing from the binary distribution is fairly simple, while compiling from source is a much more involved process. In the above mentioned link, you only need to complete one of the two sections to have a working installation

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to computer science so I don't understand what you mean when you say "find a binary distribution for your os" or "compile it yourself." Can you clarify and provide a more in-depth answer, please?

Comment: I added a bit more details and a link to the install documentation

Answer (score -2):

You need to install the files using pip because python will look in a certain directory containing packages when you do an import statement. This way, you can import the package in any python code file you do. Installing it puts it in said directory.

Alternatively, you can import a file or directory, so you could download the git files and put it in the working directory of your code file. This works because you can import files/directories that are in your current working directory. (Note that if you make a different file and want to use it there, you'll have to copy over the files to that directory too.)

Comment: OpenCV depends on native libs, so pip will not be enough for this task

Comment: Ah. I was just outlining the general process for using a python package.

Comment: @CaryShindell OpenCV is a C and C++ llibrary, even the bindings are implemented in C. There are many dependencies too. Just copying the code will not help you, no matter where you put it.